# How to say google wait until the ajax call response then crawl?

Tags: javascript, schema.org, ajax, json-ld, google-rich-snippets-tool

I've added schema markup (`ld+json` formatted) for some pages of my website. I've validated the generated schema markup script manually through the Google Rich Result tool and it' ok.

My problem is, google cannot detect it because it will be appended to the DOM after an API call (using AJAX). I mean, the page will be loaded at first and them an AJAX call happens and the generated schema markup is generated based on that AJAX call response.

So, is there any approach to tell the Google wait until for the response and schema markup get generated the crawl the page?

Comment: Generate Structured Data with JavaScript - Google for Developers https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/generate-structured-data-with-javascript

Comment: Google gives your page about 5 seconds to render its content, including adding the structured data. The real Googlebot may do better than the testing tools as it caches a lot more.

Comment: As Tony mentioned Google renders the page before it indexes it. I'ld work on the render time ... an alternative is to have the page rendered via PHP on the server using the json then deliver the rendered page. Rendering on the server can be faster sometimes because the server has a better internet connection than say someone on a smartphone.